# Sending a JSON payload to a Google Cloud Task

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, php-5.5

I'm likely missing something incredibly obvious, but in the project I'm working on I've got to send many jobs from a CSV of info to be processed asynchronously and Google App Engine's current way is through their new (beta) Cloud Tasks mechanism.

It will accept a payload as part of the task, so I was going to send a JSON array with each job's pertinent data... except that the only way to dictate the `"Content-Type: application/json"` header is during creation of the task object.

I'm using Google's own cloud-tasks 0.5.0 library.

Here is what I've been attempting, since it seems this is how most other non-cURL HTTP POST requests would accept the Content-Type header...

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\AppEngineHttpQueue;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\CloudTasksClient;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\Queue;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\Task;

<<< ...lots of cruft omitted... >>>

        $json_payload = json_encode(
            array(
                "batch" => $operation_time,
                "order" => $csvln[0],
                "customer" => $csvln[1],
                "email" => $csvln[2],
                "salesperson" => $csvln[3]
            )
        );

        //Create each of the tasks in the queue
        $options = [
            'http' => [
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $json_payload
            ]
        ];

        $task = new Task($options);
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue passing parameters to each individual task, and am finding very scant information about how to send a json body (vs a raw base64 payload string). I assume  I COULD encode the entire json body as the base64 payload then parse it in the task handler, but I assume there's a better way

Comment: I did not.  Instead I deferred to a tactic it seems Google will likely phase out in favor of these new methods... the Push Task.  Those are cake to get going though.

Comment: I understand you have found a workaround to solve this issue, correct? Can you share the documentation you used to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can load a task into the Task Queue with a pre-defined payload using an [App Engine HTTP Request](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3#google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.AppEngineHttpRequest) from the [Cloud Tasks PHP Client Library](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.86.0/tasks/v2beta3/cloudtasksclient?method=createTask).

After you defined the Task, you can use the setter methods provided to you by [AppEngineHttpRequest](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.86.0/tasks/v2beta3/appenginehttprequest) to construct your HTTP object with any required headers. This will also allow to assign the payload.

Below is a simple snippet showing how to attach a task with a payload to the default queue:

```
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\AppEngineHttpRequest;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\HttpMethod;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2beta3\Task;

//Preparing the payload
$json_payload = json_encode(
    array(
        "batch"       => date("h:i:sa"),
        "order"       => "Payload-0000",
        "customer"    => "Payload-0001",
        "email"       => "Payload-0002",
        "salesperson" => "Payload-0003"
    )
);

//Create and configure the task   
$httpR=new AppEngineHttpRequest();
$httpR->setBody($json_payload);
$httpR->setHeaders(['Content-type'=>'application/json']);
$httpR->setHttpMethod(HttpMethod::POST);   
$httpR->setRelativeUri("/example_task_handler");

$task = new Task();
$task->setAppEngineHttpRequest($httpR);
```

Also consider updating your library as the current version is v0.86.0 which it will allow the assignation of headers even after the creation of the task object.

Comment: @smoopins Hey, I am glad this works for you. You could upvote my answer if you wish.

Comment: Hit the button, but I lack the street-cred still for it to show.   Someday I'll be good in the eyes of the StackOverflow lords!  ;)

Comment: @smoopins Thanks for trying. All the best.